# about change href value from the root not by click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Thanks in advance for helps

trying to create redirect page for external links

Here , i need to change `href` with `class="external"` from the root (recreate it) , not to create click event to open window with customized href

```
<a class="external" href="http://google.com">GOOGLE</a>
```

see this

```
$('a.external').click(function (e) { 
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var target = e.target || e.srcElement; 
        if ($(target).attr('target') == "_blank") { 
          window.open("http://"+redirectpage+"?url=" +$(target).attr('href') , "_blank"); 
        } else { 
            window.location = "http://"+redirectpage +"?url="+ $(target).attr('href')); 
        }
    })
```

the above example if you copy the link by right click on
[GOOGLE](http://google.com) it will copy the original link http:// google .com

**But** 
i want to convert the original link whatever , when i click to open this link OR when i copy it the result =

http://example.com/redirect.html?url=http://google.com/

the redirect page i use http:// example .com/redirect.html
contains this

**html**

```
<a id="gotoexternal" href="">go to external</a>
```

**js**

```
<script> 
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1); 
    query = query.replace("url=", ""); 
    $('#gotoexternal').attr('href', query);  
    </script>
```

Comment: do the links exist when code runs? code should work assuming no errors are thrown anywhere and elements exist at run time.

Comment: yes and it works good, no errors

Comment: all i want recreate the link by adding strings before and after href value as the code , hope to understand my question thanx :)

Comment: oh you mean get rid of `window.location`. Now I get it.

Comment: need to use link by copying or click = replace links to generate redirect link in all cases href = http://example.com/redirect.html?url=http://google.com/

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra closing parentheses in your `window.location` line.

Should be

```
window.location = "http://"+redirectpage +"?url="+ $(target).attr('href');
```

Comment: thanx for Reference Evil

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.external').each(function () { 
    $(this).attr( 'href', "http://"+redirectpage +"?url="+ $(this).attr('href') );
    $(this).removeAttr( 'target' ); //strip target _blank from links
});
```

This simply does a one time replacement of the url with the redirection url. It requires no onclick events and no messing with target or anything else. Unless there is some reason that you want to maintain the original url that you haven't mentioned, this should be the most straightforward way to achieve what you want.

Comment: @MamdouhWinningstar you want all the links not to have target=_blank? Check my code update.

Comment: thanx brother for help but why the link opend as _blank ? what's wrong?

do you check adfly link converter script

they use DOMAssistant lib and i cant find the part thats help me

https://cdn.adf.ly/js/link-converter.js

Comment: _blank = empty page :)

Comment: @MamdouhWinningstar I'm sorry, I'm a bit confused. Are you saying that with the code I provided, the clicked links still open in a separate tab/window? Or that the link opens in the same tab, but the new page is blank?

Comment: i need to somethin look likes adfly link converter

it convert all links Begins with adf.ly + id_folder + link

Comment: sorry for my english 

it open in new tab but empty page

Comment: @MamdouhWinningstar there was absolutely nothing like that mentioned in your question...why are you changing the scope now? In addition your comments are not very concise and are confusing

Comment: sorry im new here on greate stackoverflow

Comment: replace old href to redirect url that all i need

Comment: @MamdouhWinningstar all DOMassistant does is function like jQuery. The adf.ly script functions almost identically to the one I provide, and nowhere does it handle the link 'target' attribute. Could you please update your question with where the 'redirectpage' variable is coming from and what you get when you copy and paste the url?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `attr(attributeName,function)` to modify the existing `href`

```
$('a.external').attr('href',function(_, oldHref) { 
    return  "http://" + redirectpage + "?url=" + oldHref;
});
```

the `target` should be already set according to your code

You can also do this right in a click handler so the user can't see the changes when hovering links

```
$('a.external').click(function (e) { 
      this.href = "http://" + redirectpage + "?url=" + this.href;
});
```

Reference: **[attr(attributeName,function) Docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function)**